# How can I push one element far left, and the other element far right, nested in the same container?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have a container that has a list of text and a corresponding icon for each line. I cannot get the text to align, far left, and the icons to align far right. Also, the icons are horizontally oriented based of text length. I've already separated the text and icon to be their own separate identities using a div.

Below are the CSS properties I use:

```
    chartInputSymbols: { // this is the class I use for the text
        overflow: "auto",
        float: "right",
    },
    circlePlus: { //this is the class I will be using for the icons
       
    },
}));
```

Here is the strucutre of my HTML, I'm using react-materialUI. Most code is missing for brevity.

```
                        <ListItem>
                             {value}
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <div style={{ marginLeft: "2rem" }}>
                                <Checkbox/>
                                </div>
                            </ListItemIcon>                              
                        </ListItem>)
```

[image]

How can I neatly move the text as far left of my container, and icon far right, while having equal distance in between?

Comment: Can u please share a snippet

Comment: You can give the **ol / ul** `display: flex;` and add `justifyContent / justify-content: space-between;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the flex method as explained by cloned in his/her answer. But there's another in **Material-ui** `List` to achieve this. You can use the `ListItemSecondaryAction` element, it places the element inside the element on the far right side.
Read more about `ListItemSecondaryAction` [here](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#list-controls)

```
<ListItem>
  <ListItemText primary="Single-line item" />
  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <Checkbox/>
  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
</ListItem>
```

Here is a working demo of this:
[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the way to proceed for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), using [justify-content: space-between](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

There are some other ways this can be done with flexbox, for example you can also set `margin-left: auto` on the item which shall be pushed to the right.

```css
.space-between {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fake-icon::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="space-between">
    <span> Text </span> <span class="fake-icon"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="space-between">
    <span> Longer Text </span> <span class="fake-icon"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="space-between">
    <span> A </span> <span class="fake-icon"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```